# Entity Framework map foreign key to parts of composite key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design

My database schema stores details about a person in multiple different tables some of them are culture specific some are not. Each table uses a GUID as PK and so far it works just fine.

Now I want to store localised parts in the database too. My current train of thought is to make a composite key out of two properties: a) The GUID b) the culture the item is is.
I could use a composite foreign key for my relationships, but since some of them are not to be localised this would pollute my models with unnecessary data.

Therefore my question is: Is it possible to map foreign keys to parts of composite keys, or do I have the wrong idea? In the application objects with the same ID are considered the same, just in different languages, therefore I cannot simply give out another GUID to store them as different objects.

Here is an example of my code:

This he following class defines the main part of the database. It gets retrieved and everything else is just further details.

```
[Table("Characters")]
internal class CharacterDataContract
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Culture { get; set; }

    public virtual MetadataDataContract Metadata { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Rest of code left out for brevity
}
```

This is the code that gives me headaches. The contents of this table are not localisable and will never be. How can I link the metadata class correctly to the Character class, with only the ID as foreign key?

```
[Table("Metadata")]
internal class MetadataDataContract
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Character")]
    public Guid CharacterId { get; set; }

    public CharacterDataContract Character { get; set; }

    // Rest of code left out for brevity
}
```

One additional reason why I would do this:
If I would link the ForeignKey on the metadata object to the complete PrimaryKey on the Character object I'd get data duplication in the Metadata table. However the Metadata object is CultureInvariant and can be used on any Character object with the same CharacterId, regardless of the culture the character object has.

Comment: If your primary key is made up from n columns, then **all** your foreign keys **MUST** also have those n columns - you **cannot** reference half a primary key - all or nothing only

Comment: Then how would I map my foreign key on the metadata class to the (now) unique Id class?